free(): double free detected in tcache 2 in resize() clipsai
Project: clipsai
All dependencies are installed, clipsai works pretty well with Nouveau.
When i try resize video with Nvidia driver, i have:
[nltk_data] Downloading package punkt to /home/vlad/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]   Package punkt is already up-to-date!
/home/vlad/bin/clipsai-project/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyannote/audio/core/io.py:43: UserWarning: torchaudio._backend.set_audio_backend has been deprecated. With dispatcher enabled, this function is no-op. You can remove the function call.
  torchaudio.set_audio_backend("soundfile")
INFO:pyscenedetect:Downscale factor set to 5, effective resolution: 256 x 144
INFO:pyscenedetect:Detecting scenes...
free(): double free detected in tcache 2
[1]    19517 IOT instruction (core dumped)  python crop.py

And code is exit.
My code:
import configparser, os, os.path

from clipsai import resize, AudioVideoFile, MediaEditor


config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('settings.ini')
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = config['Default']['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES']

SourceVideo = config['Default']['SourceVideo']
OutputVideo = config['Default']['OutputVideo']
ResizeVideo = config['Default']['ResizeVideo']
PyannoteToken = config['Default']['PyannoteToken']
Name = config['Default']['Name']
media_editor = MediaEditor()


def resize(PyannoteToken, OutputVideo, num_clip, Name, ResizeVideo):
    crop = resize(
        video_file_path = f'{OutputVideo}{Name}-clip{num_clip}.mp4',
        pyannote_auth_token = PyannoteToken,
        aspect_ratio=(9, 16),
    )

    media_file = AudioVideoFile(f'{OutputVideo}{Name}-clip{num_clip}.mp4')

    resized_video_file = media_editor.resize_video(
        original_video_file=media_file,
        resized_video_file_path=f'{ResizeVideo}{Name}-clip{num_clip}(crop).mp4',  # doesn't exist yet
        width=crop.crop_width,
        height=crop.crop_height,
        segments=crop.to_dict()["segments"],
    )
if __name__ == '__main__':
    num_clip = 0
    for clip in range(1, len(os.listdir(OutputVideo))):
        num_clip += 1
        resize(PyannoteToken, OutputVideo, num_clip, Name, ResizeVideo) # this



nvidia-smi:
Sun Apr 21 20:13:21 2024       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 550.76                 Driver Version: 550.76         CUDA Version: 12.4     |
|-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id          Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |           Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                        |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+========================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2070        Off |   00000000:0A:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  0%   43C    P8             18W /  175W |     431MiB /   8192MiB |      1%      Default |
|                                         |                        |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+
                                                                                         
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                              |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                              GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                               Usage      |
|=========================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A       865      G   /usr/lib/Xorg                                  15MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A       950      G   /usr/bin/kwalletd6                              1MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A       977      G   /usr/bin/kwin_wayland                          78MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1061      G   /usr/bin/Xwayland                               2MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1102      G   /usr/bin/ksmserver                              1MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1104      G   /usr/bin/kded6                                  1MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1134      G   /usr/bin/plasmashell                           65MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1168      G   /usr/lib/kactivitymanagerd                      1MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1175      G   ...b/polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1          1MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1176      G   /usr/lib/org_kde_powerdevil                     1MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1177      G   /usr/lib/xdg-desktop-portal-kde                 1MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1394      G   /usr/lib/kdeconnectd                            1MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1443      G   /usr/bin/kclockd                                1MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1453      G   /usr/bin/usbguard-qt                            1MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1463      G   /usr/bin/kaccess                                1MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1468      G   /usr/lib/DiscoverNotifier                       1MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1469      G   /usr/bin/kalendarac                             1MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1621      G   /usr/bin/konsole                                1MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1772      G   /usr/bin/dolphin                                1MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3015      G   ...apHandler --variations-seed-version        124MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     16983      G   /usr/bin/kate                                   1MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     18631      G   ...erProcess --variations-seed-version         28MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     20157      G   /usr/lib/kf6/kioworker                          1MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

glxinfo -B:
name of display: :1
display: :1  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
Memory info (GL_NVX_gpu_memory_info):
    Dedicated video memory: 8192 MB
    Total available memory: 8192 MB
    Currently available dedicated video memory: 7492 MB
OpenGL vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL renderer string: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2070/PCIe/SSE2
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 550.76
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.60 NVIDIA
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile

OpenGL version string: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 550.76
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.60 NVIDIA
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: (none)

OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 NVIDIA 550.76
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20


set device parameter in resize() function (cuda or cpu) nothing change
set CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES environment nothing change. (0, 1, " ", etc) (for Transcriber() environment is working)
For Transcriber() CUDA work pretty well
If i change driver to nouveau, i have normal output and video successfully resize:
INFO:pyscenedetect:Downscale factor set to 5, effective resolution: 256 x 144
INFO:pyscenedetect:Detecting scenes...
WARNING: All log messages before absl::InitializeLog() is called are written to STDERR
I0000 00:00:1713724103.863680    2544 gl_context_egl.cc:85] Successfully initialized EGL. Major : 1 Minor: 5
I0000 00:00:1713724103.865078    2850 gl_context.cc:357] GL version: 3.2 (OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 24.1.0-devel (git-65f5f1559f)), renderer: NV166
INFO: Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK delegate for CPU.
ffmpeg version n6.1.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 13.2.1 (GCC) 20230801
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --disable-debug ...(etc)

What can I miss in a session with nvidia drivers?
It would suit me if the work was done through the cpu, but it doesn't work in any way.

That's a bug, possibly not in your code.
